# My SDL application's window is popping up and immediately disappearing

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, c++11, sdl

I'm making a simple SDL app, but for some reason my window will not stay up and the program crashes. Here is the code:

```
bool CApp::onInit() {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
        return false;

    display = SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BPP, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    // Window pops up and disappears here.
    if(display == nullptr)  // display is NOT null
        return false;

    // Load the grid
    Grid = CSurface::onLoad("Resources\\Images\\Grid.png");
    if(Grid == nullptr)
        return false;  // Program crashes here due to onLoad returning nullptr.

    // Load the X mark
    X = CSurface::onLoad("Resources\\Images\\X.png");
    if(X == nullptr)
        return false;

    // Load the O mark
    O = CSurface::onLoad("Resources\\Images\\O.png");
    if(X == nullptr)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Read the comments to see where the program errors.

Here is the `CSurface::onLoad()` function.

```
SDL_Surface* CSurface::onLoad(char* File) {
    SDL_Surface* surfTemp = nullptr;    // Temporary Surface
    SDL_Surface* surfReturn = nullptr;  // Return Surface

    surfTemp = SDL_LoadBMP(File); // This returns a nullptr for some reason

    if(surfTemp == nullptr)
        return nullptr;       // This is the culprit for the program crashing.

    // Optimize and free our surface.
    surfReturn = SDL_DisplayFormat(surfTemp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surfTemp);

    return surfReturn;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is not working. It has worked before, but now, it just crashes!

Comment: why the // in the file name?  Also when you switch to IMG_Load(File) is it still returning null?  Do you have the file in the correct location?  Do you need elevated permission to access it?

Comment: '\\' is an escape character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 problems:

1)

```
// Load the X mark
X = CSurface::onLoad("Resources\\Images\\X.png");
if(X == nullptr)
    return false;

// Load the O mark
O = CSurface::onLoad("Resources\\Images\\O.png");
if(X == nullptr)
    return false;
```

The second check should be evaluating O rather than X.

2) You're loading a png image using `SDL_LoadBMP`. Try using `IMG_Load` from the [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) extension. This is why it's returning `nullptr`. `SDL_LoadBMP` is expecting a BMP header and it's not getting it.

Comment: It's not the answer to the problem. Although that is helpful, it's not what I was asking. I do appreciate the find though!

Comment: Well, the file names look suspect to me. why the double slashes?

Comment: A single slash represents the start of an escape sequence. Double slashes are required in this case.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 That's not the problem. I have pointed out where the problem is in the code.

Comment: Also, it works fine with that function. I have used it before for a png. It even works for jpg's too.

Comment: @Tux You can't load a PNG or a JPG with a function that expects a `BMP`, as the file formats are different. You were just lucky until then.

Comment: @Tux [This documentation page](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_LoadBMP) specifies that the function loads a BMP image. You're passing in a PNG path, and you're getting a null pointer. It's to be expected :v

Comment: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-image
Yep, you should include "SDL_image.h", link SDL_image.lib and use IMG_Load(File);

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about SDL_image. One of my coworkers kept insisting that `SDL_LoadBMP()` could load PNGs. Guess he was wrong! :P

Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this on my machine, and think I found your error.

Your using SDL_LoadBMP yet you are trying to load a PNG file.
SDL_LoadBMP can only open supported Windows Bitmap files

If your images have to be in a format other than BMP,
the SDL_Image library will give you a set of functions for opening other types of images.
http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/